# Tableau - calculate a new data point or break out a category

Tags: tableau-api, lookup

[animal farm tableau workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PYpe1bxZEQ9480_Kv55jgDzPmaVBzphw)I have a new project that I'd like to drop into tableau, but my client needs to be able break apart one specific figure in a way that I'm not sure how best to handle.  The problem is that my categories are not mutually exclusive, so I need to pull out the double counted data.

To super simplify the problem, I made a little workbook of the count of various animals on two different farms.

Dogs, Puppies, Cat, Birds, & Horses. I want a stacked bar of the total number of animals.  The problem is, the category "dogs" also includes the puppies, so what I really need is to calculate =sum(dogs)-sum(puppies) and use that figure for "adult dogs".

[image]

My current plan is to run an index/match in excel prior to putting the data in tableau to generate the new figure of "adult dogs", but I'd love to know if there's a simpler solution (or an all in tableau solution)

I've tried playing with a few table calcs and lookups, but I'm just not getting the results I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question. I think I have it solved though. First you need to isolate the values for the puppies in a calculated field:

"Puppies":

```
IF Animal = "Puppies" THEN sales ELSE 0 END
```

This gives us a column with the puppy values, with other animals having a 0. Then we need to have a field that gets the maximum value for all animals in the puppy column, then if the category is dogs, take that from sales, otherwise just give us sales:

"Sales D - P"

```
IF Animals = 'Dogs' THEN Sales - {FIXED :MAX([Puppies Values])} ELSE Sales END
```

The FIXED calculation is allowing the calculation to be performed on other rows, not just at the row level. So here we're taking the max sales across every animal in the puppy field, which we have only giving a non-zero value if the row category is puppy. Now we have this, we only want to apply it to dogs, so we have an IF statement saying if the row is Dogs, then take the max puppy value away from sales, otherwise just give me sales

Here is a picture to demonstrate:

[image]

You could then change the alias for the animals dimension for dogs to adult dogs

Comment: This is brilliant, and worked very well!  Thank you!    Now to the process of translating this into my real data